# Why am I not getting any value (small, medium or big) when running this funtion? (I think I have to use something else instead of str())

Tags: python

I am importing a class that I am using in this function but that is unrelevant for you. My problem is that carSize2 is being skipped over when I append to my textfile

```
file = open("data", "a")
number = input("What is your license number?: ")
name = input("What is your name?: ")
carSize = input("What kind of car do you have? Please press 1 for small, 2 for medium and 3 for big: ")
carSize2 = str()
if carSize == size.small:
    carSize2=print("small")
elif carSize==size.medium:
    carSize2= print("medium")
elif carSize==size.big:
    carSize2= print("big")
startHour = input("Input the hour when you entered the parking lot(in 24h time please, no leading zeroes): ")
startMinute = input("Input the minute when you entered the parking lot: ")
endHour = input("Input the hour when you exited the parking lot(in 24h time please, no leading zeroes): ")
endMinute = input("Input the hour when you exited the parking lot: ")
file.write(
    number + " " + carSize2 + " " + name + " " + "you entered the parking lot at " + startHour + ":" + startMinute + " and left at " + endHour + ":" + endMinute)
print("OK!")
```

Comment: What happens if you `print(carSize)`?

Comment: `print()` returns None... What are you expecting `carSize2 = print()` to do?

Comment: If I input 1 it should print out "small". If I input 2 it should print out "medium", and then 3 prints out "big" but I am not getting any of those. carSize2 just gets skipped over

Comment: It's hard to answer this since `size` is undefined

Comment: "I am using this class" what class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`carSize = print("big")` prints, but it assigns `carSize` to `None`. You have to split into `carSize = "big"` and `print(carSize)`.

---

You are printing it in terminal because you use `print()` which prints it in the terminal. Instead, print in text file using `file.write()`.

Comment: It does something: it prints `"big"` and assigns the return value of `print` (namely, `None`) to the name `carSize`.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem of a variable being "skipped"

Comment: Not necessarily. Just saying maybe understand the question better?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the OP means by "skipped"

Comment: "when appending to file" ... `file.write(number + " " + carSize2`, where `carSize2` is either `None` or `str()`. If it actually were None, then that is what would appear in the file, not an empty string, indicating the if statemtents are not working

Comment: Ok guys! I am gonna take a look at the code again and write back

Comment: this is my class: class Size:
    def __init__(self, small: int, medium: int, big: int):
        self.small= small
        self.medium= medium
        self.big= big

size= Size(1,2,3)

Comment: Your class has ``int``. Therefore, you need to use ``int(input())`` instead of ``input()``.

Comment: with "skipped over" I meant that in the file instead of getting "small, "medium" or "big" I just get an empty space

Comment: See @OneCricketeer's answer

Comment: Okay it works now!! i just want to get rid of the "small", "medium" or "big" that gets printed out in the terminal after I typed 1,2 or 3. I just want it to get printed inside my text file not in my terminal. I think str() is causing this but I dont know what to write instead

Comment: @JoJo You are printing it in terminal because you use print() which prints it in the terminal. Instead, print in text file using file.write().

Comment: THANK YOU! It works perfectly! Thanks to everyone who helped!!!

Comment: @JoJo You can accept my answer by clicking the gray checkmark

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what your import for `size` does, so it does matter. If you are comparing a string to an int, it would be "skipped"

You also should assign the value to a string rather than to a call to print function

```
carSize = int(input("What kind of car do you have? Please press 1 for small, 2 for medium and 3 for big: "))

if carSize == 1:
    carSize2 = "small"
elif carSize == 2:
    carSize2 = "medium"
elif carSize == 3:
    carSize2 = "big"
else:
    raise Error("Invalid Input")
```